# excel vba synchronization issue

Tags: vba, excel, synchronization

I'm using excel to do some data analysis work.
the scenario is like this:
I use some excel plug-in componnets to get data from remote site.
for example, put `=get_the_latest_data(ID)` in `A1`, then this function would be called and ID's data would be filled in `A2` to `A11`.
My goal is

```
for each id in id_array
    sheet1.range("a1") = get_the_latest_data(id)
    create a new sheet named id
    save data from a2 to a11 to thi new sheet
next
```

My problem is it would take some time for `get_the_latest_data` function to get all the data from remote. So, in my code the new sheet couldn't get the right result. I tried to use application.wait before copy data from sheet1 to the new sheet.
but it didn't work.

Is there any way I can make sure that  data is copied to the new sheet  after the wanted data is got from remote? btw，I do not have access to the source code of `get_the_latest_data`.

Comment: you can add a loop to wait for the cell's value to be not empty? `worksheet_change` may help you too but you need to carefully enable/disable event in your own code

Comment: Try this Addd `DoEvents` after this line `sheet1.range("a1") = get_the_latest_data(id)`

Comment: please can  you let us know what mechanism `get_the_latest_data(ID)` uses? I get data from all sorts of places and have never encountered this problem before as my `VBA` generally waits for each line to completely finish before moving to the next line

Comment: @whytheq actually this might be where the root cause. I have no idea how the get_the_latest_data works. to be more specificly, the software providing this function is called wind, something  like bloomberg that you can use to get financial datas. When I start the "wind" software and log in. some buttons would be added to My excel and I would be able to call functions it provides.

Comment: I tried the method mentioned by @peter-albert, sometimes it works, sometimes it would hang in the while loop.I was wondering if the "wind" add some restrictions that its functions couldn't be called too frequently so that its server won't suffer from too much pressure.If I add a msgbox("finishe one procedure") in the code ,which means I have to click the button each time,it would successfully do what I want;however when I remove the "msgbox",no matter whether I use applicaion.wait or do some long long calculation loop, it would always fail.

Comment: Did you try what I suggested?

Comment: @user1871453 Can I assume that you would be comfortable with an synchronus request here? :) Because you want to get all the data first then try to add them into the sheets. +1 for the question.

Comment: @whytheq not necessarily. There are certain applications which might have ashynchronus requests (Which is not very well exposed to the user) so in such cases unless otherwise user specifically check with them, situations like this could arise... I suspect this is like a data vendor ;) OP if you can show your code a bit more it's helpful to help you.

Comment: Are you using [Wind Info](http://www.wind.com.cn/En/Default.aspx)? If so can I suggest you try their email support Service@wind.com.cn?

Answer (score 3):

Normally, VBA only executes the next step after the former step is fully finished. That is unless the call triggers some background action (e.g. to Refresh a data connection that has "Background refresh" enabled.

You can do the following to solve the issue:

**Disable background refresh:** If you look in the properties of the connection, unselect "Enable background refresh"

**Wait until refresh is finished with data query specific check:** Modify your code the following way:

```
    Range("A11").Clear               'To enable the check
    subCallToTriggerDataLoadHere
    While Range("A11").Value  ""   'Or any other specific check to see that your refresh is finished
        DoEvents
    Wend
    ...
```

**Use the AfterRefresh event of a query:** [See this post for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585369/excel-vba-and-refreshall-ended-message)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a typcal case with a third party data vendor where their generics data-requests are **ashynchronus** which is not very well exposed to the users. In such cases you may need to check with your vendor for the behaviour of that method you are calling. There has to be some `boolean` type of a variable to be set at least to choose to either have a asynch or synch request/retrieve.

Eg. if you are sending one index ticker to get top 10 members, then this method is right now collecting all your index tickers and shooting you back with all the data. So check if the returned data could be **split** e.g. it's a multi-dimensional array that you could separate the data into the sheets based on the `id`. Else talk to this application's API developers as `DoEvents` might be too weak to handle this.

---

<strike>I suggest you to use anarrayList/collection item to hold the data returned from your method for each id. Once it's completed you can start creating sheets as you already have caught the data locally.</strike>

```
Dim al as Object

Set al = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
for each id in id_array
    al.add get_the_latest_data(id) '--possibly returning a variant
next

'--for each item in arrayList then you create a sheet by outputing the data    

for i = 0 to al.Count
   '--Create new sheet put your code here
   '--transpose the data 
   Sheets(i+1).Range("A2").Resize(UBound(al(i))) = Application.Transpose(al(i))
Next i
```

Comment: @user1871453 Please give this a try.

Comment: Is there any "stupid" method I could use to "sleep" or "wait" some time after calling this ashynchronus data-requests so that my sheet is filled with the returning data. I'm in no hurry to deal with the returning data,just don't want to change the id mannually. Actually I'm curious why application.wait doesn't work.